# WPF MarkupExtension binding error

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, markup-extensions

refers to [implementing a multilanguage interface](https://wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html) now I have a problem. I have a `grid` where its `ItemSource` it's  a `Dictionary<string, string>`: I can't give the key value as parameter of the markup extension because I have the following exception

```
A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Value1' property of type 'TranslateMarkupExtension'. 
A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.
```

This is the xaml where I use the markup extension:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary}" Grid.Row="0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="{TranslateMarkup Value1 = {Binding Path = Key}}" Grid.Column="0" /> 
                    <TextBox Tag="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}" Width="200" Height="46" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" LostFocus="TextBox_OnLostFocus" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I can't find any workaround..I need the dictionary as item source because the label will show the key and the textbox the corresponding value..I tried also replacing the dictionary with a list of object but the problem still remains.

Does anyone have a good hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A [value converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) would work.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Ed Plunkett, the **solution** is the `ValueConverter`.

So the label is know this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Key, Converter={StaticResource MultiLangConverter}}" Grid.Column="0" />
```

where my ValueConverter is the following:

```
public class StringToMultiLangConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var stringValue = (string) value;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
            return string.Empty;
        string multiLang = LangTranslator.GetString(stringValue);
        return multiLang ?? value;
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!